# How to orderBy a array of objects in descending order in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, angular-filters, angularjs-orderby

I have a very simple array of objects and I want to sort it using `$filter('orderBy')` in javascript. Somehow it doesn't seem to work. [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/saras_arya/1bcmo74j/)

Here is the code

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('myController', function($scope, $filter){
    var person = [{
  name : "Saras"
  },
  {
  name : "Arya"
  }];
  $filter('orderBy')(person, 'name');
  console.log(person);
});
```

I don't understand why I can't get this to work? Help is appreciated. And the solution should be in JS not in HTML.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should pass 2nd parameter as property name `name`, then assign that filtered result to desire scope variable wherever you want. So there will not be any filtering needs to be done on UI `ng-repeat` output.

```
$scope.person = $filter('orderBy')(person, 'name');

<div  ng-repeat="p in person">
   {{p.name}}
</div>
```

[**Forked Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/b0ao82y2/) Here

---

If you wanted to see it on view you should keep that property on one of scope variable, or rather you can do this simple filtering on client side as well while displaying records.

```
<div  ng-repeat="p in person | orderBy: 'name'">
   {{p.name}}
</div>
```

[**Demo here**](https://jsfiddle.net/zsjs93bL/)

Comment: It doesn't work... Could you post the link of a working fiddle... From the one given in question.

Comment: I have updated my answer, could you please look into the fiddle which I have in my answer?

Comment: Can't the $scope.person array be modified in the controller file?

Comment: @SarasArya yes, it can be modified from controller

Comment: @SarasArya here you go, find fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/b0ao82y2/)

Comment: Okay, so the mistake was. I was thinking that $filter('orderBy') would change the array itself. It didn't you have to get the output in another variable which does the trick. Is it right?

Comment: correct. that will return a new array which is filtered one, you have to reassign back to the desired variable again to see the changes

Comment: if you want to sort in descending order then set true in third parameter like this: $scope.person = $filter('orderBy')(person, 'name', true);

Comment: @PankajParkar That's a perfect answer(both ways), it works well!!. However, for descending order covered by SumitJoshi. Thanks.

Answer (score 12):

Adding + or - prefix on orderBy parameter will order by + (ascending) or -(desc);

example:

```
<li ng-repeat="x in customers | orderBy : '-city'">
    {{x.name + ", " + x.city}}
</li>
```

more at : http://www.w3schools.com/angular/ng_filter_orderby.asp

Or if you want to console.log it then just add name as parameter in quotations :

```
$filter('orderBy')(person, 'name');
```

Comment: U can also use ! : <li ng-repeat="x in customers | orderBy : '!city'">

Answer (score 1):

Example:

```
<tr ng-repeat="friend in friends | orderBy:'-age'">
    <td>{{friend.age}}</td>
    <td>{{friend.name}}</td>
</tr>
```

Use '-' Symbol Before your expression

Comment: Hi Muhammad, can you explain what your answer provides in addition to the already given answers?

Comment: @ArtjomB. I give that what expression should have to use beside value . for clarification . i give comments

Answer (score 0):

`$scope.person  = $filter('orderBy')($scope.person , 'name', true);`

true for descending order and 
false for ascending order